# Keyboard shortcuts not showing in menu since 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, menu

Since I upgraded to 16.04 LTS keyboard shortcuts aren't showing in the menu anymore for several major programs.

These programs include all browsers: Firefox, Chromium, Opera, several KDE programs like Okular, Krusader and other programs like Atom, VLC, SMplayer, KeepassX, Thunderbird.

This a major nuisance, how do I enable them again?